# Is there an equivalent pop method in Ruby for hashes similar to Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, ruby, hash

In Python you can do something like:

```
d = {"Austria": "Vienna", "Peru": "Lima"}
d.pop("Austria")
```

"Vienna" is returned, and the "Austria":"Vienna" pair is deleted from d.

Is there something analogous in Ruby? I think I know the answer but I haven't seen this asked yet on SO and want to confirm I'm correct.

Comment: I'm curious if you think you know the answer, why don't you try it?

Comment: I did. But I always like to get confirmation and make sure I'm not missing some details or side-effects.

Comment: Doc never lies.. You can read it as many times as you want. It is perfectly written in the *doco*.

Comment: It's important to be able to figure stuff out without asking. That's why we have documentation, and tools like IRB, which lets us try and experiment and SEE whether things work. Asking questions that show you haven't read, or tried, will only irritate those who you could end up working with; Trying is an important characteristic for a programmer.

Comment: @theTinMan, you are showing your age by your use of the term "programmer".

Comment: No, it's showing a corporate/enterprise view of a very general job. I "code"|"develop programs"|"engineer software solutions" all day long for my job but it's not even in my title.

Comment: @the-tin-man Before I asked this question, I read the documentation, tried it in the respective interpreters, and then asked the question since it wasn't asked on SO. Doing so is an important characteristic for getting rep on SO.

Comment: I like the terms "programmer" and "coder", which reflect the way the profession was originally viewed: as a craft.  Despite the advances in computer science as an academic discipline, I still think of the worker bees as primarily craftsmen and craftswomen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hash#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-delete) is similar to `dict.pop` in Python.

```
h = {"Austria" => "Vienna", "Peru" => "Lima"}
h.delete("Austria")
# => "Vienna"
h
# => {"Peru"=>"Lima"}
```

Comment: It was close between you and Nick (I saw those edits flying), but you edged him out because the final result after 15 minutes was more complete and clearer. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 2):

Yup, `delete`.

```
[1] pry(main)> d = { "Austria" => "Vienna", "Peru" => "Lima" }
=> {"Austria"=>"Vienna", "Peru"=>"Lima"}
[2] pry(main)> d.delete('Austria')
=> "Vienna"
[3] pry(main)> d
=> {"Peru"=>"Lima"}
```